# Google Colaboratory で Python のバージョンを3.7に変更したい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

インストールしたいライブラリがPython3.7に対応しています。しかし、google colaboratoryのPythonのバージョンが3.8.5のようで、インストールができず困っています。
ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/` 以下に Python 3.7 が入っていなかったので、まず python3.7 パッケージをインストールした後、`update-alternatives` コマンドでバージョン切り替えの候補に追加します。

```bash
!sudo apt install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

続けて以下のコマンドを実行すると Python のバージョン選択の画面になります。
`*` の付いている 3.8 が現在のデフォルトになっているので、先ほど追加した 3.7 を選ぶには `2` を入力します。

```
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3

There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

設定後、Python のバージョンが切り替わっているかを確認してください。

```
!python --version
Python 3.7.15
```

**参考:**
[How to Change Python Version in Google Colab : 3 Steps Only](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/change-python-version-in-google-colab-steps/)